# YouTube video not loading into AS2 Flash

Tags: flash, youtube, actionscript-2

I'm trying to make a Flash movie which will load a Flash video within itself. This is the code I was using and it had been working, but since changing the video URL it no longer loads.

```
this.createEmptyMovieClip("youTube_mc", this.getNextHighestDepth());
this.youTube_mc.loadMovie("https://www.youtube.com/v/22RBuZJ6J7k?version=3&autoplay=1");
```

Is anyone able to offer any help with this? It is vexing me somewhat. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The youtube player is AS3 based, that's your issue. I would suggest moving to AS3 and checking out their API.

Comment: I feared this would be the answer. Guess it's time I sat down and updated all of our templates to AS3.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to work by using the HTML for embedding a Youtube video and loading that into a text box's HTMLText. I used to do this all the time when I couldn't get it to work 0:) It's also how I imported images from URLS haha!

```
myTextObject.htmlText ="/*YouTube embed code here (iFrame may not work.. try their old embed code if you can find it online)*/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the player version 2 it works for me in AS2, default version is not working so "?version=2" part is necessary

```
    box.loadMovie("http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=2");
    or
    box.loadMovie("http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=2");
```

just type the VIDEO_ID in the above commands
check this too
https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference_as2